# Rails: Generated controller syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When creating a new resource using `rails generate scaffold person`, the following controller action is created for `destroy`:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    @person.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to people_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

I have always replicated this syntax when writing my own `destroy` actions.

My question is, why does the generated code:

1. assign an instance variable that is never used?
2. perform two database calls when only one is required?

Is the following code equivalent, or is there a reason it is not done this way?

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    Person.destroy(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to people_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: They are functionally equivalent. My guess is that it's that way for consistency - all the other default actions set an instance variable, why have an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look at [the source code](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy) reveals that `Person.destroy(params[:id])` is equivalent to `Person.find(params[:id]).destroy`:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb, line 377
def destroy(id)
  if id.is_a?(Array)
    id.map { |one_id| destroy(one_id) }
  else
    find(id).destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting, so the performance of both approaches should be the same, it's just that one is superfluous.